# File Not Found error for \includegraphics{file}, BUT not consistently after the recent update of TexPad

Tags: mac, includegraphics, texpad

I have been using the updated version of TeXpad recently, and I am coming across some issues that I cannot render. I am creating `beamer` slides and the `\includegraphics` command is not working properly. There are times when it works and when it doesn't. I am currently in the

> "LaTeX Error: File `___' not found"

category. Whereas yesterday morning it was working fine, with an occasional not working. I am not certain, if this is because of the LIVE updating or not. Please advise. I am including a screen shoot with my code and root file for the document.

So, I created a simple file to test out the problem. I have been able to reproduce this several times. Here is what I did.

I created a file in the same directory with this simple code.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

And dragged in a `*.png` image, and TeXpad auto includes the command `\includegraphics{strat1}` and it works fine. Then, I quit TeXpad, reopen the file with TeXpad, and it gives me the error of file not found. Then, I reopened the file with TeXshop and it compiles just fine. Has anyone had similar problem? Is TeXpad not using the same root folder for the rendering? can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is due to TexPad's sandboxing feature. The article linked below describes methods to grant access to resolve the issue:

https://www.texpad.com/support/macos/about/sandboxing